# Нет перевода текста ошибки, когда пытаешься нажать "сохранить изменения" в сообщении из очереди проверок, при этом не внеся никаких изменений

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок, правки

Нет перевода текста ошибки, когда пытаешься нажать "сохранить изменения" в сообщении, при этом не внеся никаких изменений:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм-м ... а у меня просто закрывает редактор и всё. Без лишних сообщений. Видимо, всё же надо ещё что-то сделать, кроме как просто открыть на редактирование и попытаться сохранить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вообще, я это в очереди проверок делал. Может в этом дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/765

Предложил:

> Вам необходимо внести какие-нибудь изменения перед сохранением.

Comment: Утвердил с поправленной опечаткой :)