# Что делать, если тревога была принята, но никаких действий не последовало?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

[Нет перевода текста ошибки, когда пытаешься нажать "сохранить изменения" в сообщении из очереди проверок, при этом не внеся никаких изменений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8825/15479).

Пытаюсь поставить тревогу с текстом `[статус-завершено]`, получаю:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В списке тревог, как оказалось, ранее уже делал тоже самое, тревога была принята, но метку так и не повесили.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать в таких случаях?

Comment: Побеждать на выборах!